# How to transform CSV or DB record data for Kafka and how to get it back into a csv or DF on the other side

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, apache-kafka

I've successfully set up a Kafka instance at my job and I've been able to pass simple 'Hello World' messages through it.

However, I'm not sure how to do more interesting things. I've got a CSV that contains four records from a DB that I'm trying to move through kafka, then take into a DF on the other side and save it as a CSV again.

```
producer = KafkaProducer(boostrap_servers='my-server-id:443',
               ....

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df = df.to_json()
producer.send(mytopic, df.encode('utf8'))
```

This returns code in a tuple object (conusmer.record object, bool) that contains a list of my data. I can access the data as:

```
msg[0][0][6].decode('utf8')
```

But that comes in as a single string that I can't pass to a dataframe simply (it just merges everything into one thing).

I'm not sure if I even need a dataframe or a to_json() method or anything. I'm really just not sure how to organize data to send properly and then return it and feed it back into a dataframe so that I can either a) save it to a CSV or b) reinsert the dataframe to a DB with to_Sql.

Comment: Check out Kafka Connect for doing ingest/egress. There are some examples you can follow here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-3qN_tlYR4&list=PL5T99fPsK7ppB_AbZhBhTyKHtHWZLWIJ8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka isn't really suited to send entire matricies/dataframes around.

You can send a list of CSV rows, JSON arrays, or preferrably some other compressable binary dataformat such as Avro or Protobuf as whole objects. If you are working exclusively in Python, you could `pickle` the data you send and receive.

When you read the data, you must **deserialize** it but *how* you do that, is ultimately your choice, and there is no simple answer for any given application.

The solution, for this one case, would be [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html), then `to_csv`, however... And I would like to point out that Kafka isn't required for you to test that, as you definitely should be writing unit tests...

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
jdf = df.to_json()

msg_value = jdf  # pretend you got a message from Kafka, as a JSON string 
df = pd.json_normalize(msg_value)  # back to a dataframe
df.to_csv()
```